# Does RBC Direct Investing allow to buy BMO ETF funds?

Tags: canada, online-brokerage

I'm trying to pick an online trading platform and on a first glance for choosing between major Canadian banks (RBC, BMO, TD, etc.), the RBC seems more appealing. However, I am interested in specific funds by BMO (e.g. ZFL - BMO Long Federal Bond Index ETF). Would RBC Direct Investing still allow me to buy it? More generally - can an ETF offered by BMO be bought from non-BMO investment account/system?

Comment: Have you thought about asking RBC about it directly? Sort of getting the answer directly from the horse’s mouth?

Comment: I suppose my question is more general - can an ETF offered by BMO be bought from non-BMO investment account/system? I've updated the main question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RBC Direct investing allows you to buy ETFs from the Toronto Stock Exchange.

You can get a list of available ETFs from here: https://www.tsx.com/listings/listing-with-us/sector-and-product-profiles/exchange-traded-funds

You can also sign up for a practice account https://www.rbcdirectinvesting.com/investment-choices/etfs.html and see for yourself.

Comment: That answered my question, thank you very much! To elaborate, does RBC Direct investing allow  to buy any symbol on the Toronto Stock exchange (not just ETF's)? E.g. would one be able to buy units of GTU.TO 
 https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GTU.TO/ ?

Comment: GTU was bad example, let's use CEF instead https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CEF.TO?p=CEF.TO